# In Google Earth Engine how can I find the elevation height of connected components

Tags: google-earth-engine

Requesting programming help / guidance In Google Earth Engine, to find how tall each connected patch of elevation data is in the flowing image "LabledSlopeElev" with 4 bands of information.  The first band is "labels" with unique names from "connectedComponents".  For each patch of connected Components I want to find the Max and Min value from the "elevation" band and calculate the height of the patch by subtracting the Max from the Min.  Finally, I would like to add a new band storing that height value for every pixel of the patch, such that when you click on a pixel in a patch you can see the height of the patch in the Inspector.

Here's my code so far.  I'm pretty new to this style of programming.

```
'''
var USNED = ee.Image('USGS/NED'); 
Map.setCenter(-76.816138, 39.315564, 16); // Daniles Maryland

// Load a table of state boundaries and filter.
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/States')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Maryland') );
var USNEDclip = USNED.clipToCollection(fc); //selected elevation data

var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(USNEDclip); 

// Create a "Low elevation mask" revaling all the high slope areas
var High1 = slope.gte(38.0);
Map.addLayer(High1.updateMask(High1), {palette:'fc03f4'}, 'High Elev', true); // purple is high slope areas

// Uniquely label the patches.
var patchid = High1.connectedComponents(ee.Kernel.square(1), 256);

//Concatenate the given images together, bands will be - label, slope:int, elevation, slope_1:float
var LabledSlopeElev = ee.Image.cat([patchid, USNEDclip, slope]); print('LabledSlopeElev', LabledSlopeElev);
Map.addLayer(LabledSlopeElev, {} , 'Labled Slope Elev', false);
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduceConnectedComponents for this.  It will create bands with a constant value in each patch.  Then you simply subtract them.

```
var minMax = LabledSlopeElev.select("labels", "elevation")
    .reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.minMax(), "labels", 256)
var diff = minMax.select("elevation_max")
    .subtract(minMax.select("elevation_min"))
    .rename("height")
Map.addLayer(diff, {} , 'Height', false);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bf739dc3c1f8cf87a466e0a616b2d265